# Generate all numbers of length M (1<M<10) with elements from {1,2,...N} with N(1<N<20)

Tags: c#, c

thank you for taking the time to read this.
I'm working on a larger project that needs a function that generates all numbers based on the rules described in the title.
If inputs are M=3 and N=5 Outputs should be: 111,112,113,114,115,121....555
For inputs M=4 and N=2 Outputs should be: 1111,1112,1121...2222

I've been trying to make a function that does this for quite some time but i haven't succeeded. So I'm asking for help. I'm required to write it in C, but if you know how to fix it in C++ or C# I'll probably be able to translate it into C.

I don't have any code to show because thus far I've mostly tried brute-forcing it but it doesn't seem to work
Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: what does it mean for a base-10 decimal representation to contain an element 20 without containing a 0?

Comment: I think he is trying to create some sort of number dictionary for a given length of numbers. Are you?

Comment: Can you do `M=0, N=whatever`? Or `(M=1, N=whatever)`? Then ... recurse :) .... somewhere in the recursion of `foobar(M, N)` call `foobar(M - 1, N)`

Comment: @DanielFarrell Oh, well pointed out. When it comes to elements bigger than 10 the numbers should jump up by 10. So for M=3 N=17 you'd have 111 to 1117 and then back to 121 .. 1217 and so on.

Comment: @pmg It can do M=1, N=whatever. I will try doing it using recursion, but i'm unfortunately not sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: @NoOneStudiosMadeOfStalinium For M=3 N=17, how would you distinguish 1117 (1,1,17) from 1117 (1,11,7) and 1117 (11,1,7)?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want numbers that are entirely composed of any number between 1 and N.  that's redundant; if it's composed of numbers > 10 it's also composed of the single digits < 10.  So it seems that 9 would be a functional upper end for N, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is your output a string of numerical characters or an actual numerical type?

Comment: Only makes sense for it to be the base 10 string representation, right?

Comment: It hard to undestand the question **1<N<20**????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, I would do it with regular expressions.  This is all written with C in mind.

First build a regex with all the allowed digits.  Posix provides a regex library (https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-write-regular-expressions-in-c appears to be a good intro), so you only have to compose the string that will be parsed by `regcomp()` by iterating through the numbers from 1 to N.   An appropriate regular expression would be, for N=20, `^(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)+$`.  This will match strings composed entirely of any of those characters.  (Since 0 should match only after 1 or 2 in this case, enumerating the options is simpler than trying to shorten the regex).

Then, iterate over the numbers starting with `10 ^ M` and ending when you reach `10^(M+1)`.  Write each number out as a string and see if it matches the regular expression - if it does, you have one of your results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be boiled down to starting an M-digit, base-N number at its lowest value for the initial iteration, and incrementing it for subsequent iterations.

The M-digit number can be represented as an array (indexed from 0 to M-1) with one element per digit. One end of the array will hold the lowest order ("rightmost") digit and the other end of the array will hold the highest order ("leftmost") digit. It doesn't really matter which end is chosen to hold the highest order digit, so let's choose element 0 to hold the highest order digit. For generality, let's use digit values from 0 to N-1. (It doesn't really matter that the original problem has digits going from 1 to N since it is easy to map digit values from one scheme to the other.)

We can define a function to set the M-digit number to its lowest value:

```
void num_init(unsigned int *digits, unsigned int m)
{
    while (m--)
    {
        digits[m] = 0;
    }
}
```

We can define another function to increment the M-digit number and indicate whether the number has wrapped around back to its lowest value:

```
int num_inc(unsigned int *digits, unsigned int n, unsigned int m)
{
    while (m--)
    {
        if (digits[m] < n - 1)
        {
            digits[m]++;
            return 0;
        }
        digits[m] = 0; // carry
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Print all M-digit numbers with digits from 1 to N.
void list_nums(unsigned int m, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int digits[m];
    int wrapped = 0;

    num_init(digits, m);
    while (!wrapped)
    {
        unsigned int i;

        // output an m-digit number
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            // Note: Add 1 to each digit so digits run from 1 to n instead of 0 to n-1.
            printf("%u", digits[i] + 1);
        }
        // get next number
        wrapped = num_inc(digits, n, m);
        if (!wrapped)
        {
            printf(",");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note: The output of `list_nums(m, n)` will be strange when `n` is greater than 9.